# How do I enrich my event stream with an environment variable in fluentd?

Tags: fluentd, td-agent

I have a source event stream which is coming from a log tail. I'm trying to enrich this by using the filter directive. Some searching mentioned using `#{ENV['MYVAR']}` would work but I am getting an empty string as the value. The filter is as below:

```
<filter logtag.mytag>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    mykey "#{ENV['MYVAR']}"
  </record>
</filter>
```

Is it possible to add an env variable the way I'm doing it, and if so what am I doing incorrectly? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your syntax looks correct except that you did not mention true or false for `enable_ruby`. Ex - `enable_ruby true`. what is your input looks like and what are expecting after transformer?.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I found the mistake, I didn't mention that I was using a mac environment and had to set the env variables differently from linux. Updated more in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with what Imran mentioned (set `enable_ruby` to `true`), the mistake was that I was using a mac environment and it turns out we have to set the environment variable through `launchctl` to make it work instead of exporting it in bash profile or `/etc/environment` like we do in linux.

Command:

`sudo launchctl setenv MYVAR varvalue`

After doing that, it worked right away.